# Safari hiding layer once Youtube or Vimeo starts to load

Tags: jquery, safari, youtube

For some reason Safari keeps hiding the content on the page once a Youtube or Vimeo video that is embedded in the page starts to load.

It only happens in Safari all other browsers are fine.

URL example here:
http://engagingcomms.com/marketing-branding-brand-launch-real-estate-agents-franchise-development-43

Or video of what happens:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24906574/vimeo-youtube-issue.mov

It's driving me crazy as can't figure it out. Pretty sure it's some how messing with the Jquery but not sure how as the videos are iframed in... Wouldn't of thought that could effect the scripts in the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, was a CSS issue. Once we swapped this out it finally started to work in Safari.

```
/***** Safari Vimeo Issue *****/
.case-conts:after{content: "."; display: block; clear: both; visibility: hidden; line-height: 0; height: 0}

#scrollcontent {
    min-height: 100px;
}
.scrollcontenIn {
    overflow: visible;
}
.case-conts {   
 clear: both;
 width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Chanced the Z index of the layers to fix.